# How to design a Server-Driven UI Response Structure for a Tabbed Screen with Infinite Scrolling List?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, server, backend

I am a backend developer and I am trying to use Server Driven UI to send response data including some UI to the app. I am currently designing the response structure, but I am stuck on how to design a screen that includes a list with infinite scroll for each tab.

The structure that comes to mind is as follows, but none of them meet all requirements:

1. Send tab information and the results of all tabs at once.

```json
{
  screenType: "MyTabScreen",
  sections: [
    {
      sectionType: "TabSection",
      tabs: [
        {
          tabName: "tab1",
          contents: [{...}, {...}],
          selected: true
        },
        {
          tabName: "tab2",
          contents: [{...}, {...}],
          selected: false
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This structure makes the data size too large and requires fetching all data every time the tab is changed. It also cannot implement infinite scroll.

```json
{
  screenType: "MyTabScreen",
  sections: [
    {
      sectionType: "TabSection",
      tabs: [
        {
          tabName: "tab1",
          contents: [{...}, {...}],
          selected: true
        },
        {
          tabName: "tab2",
          selected: false
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The data size is reduced, but it still cannot implement infinite scroll. Also, tab information needs to be continuously fetched even though it does not change.

Can you please advise on how to implement such cases?

Comment: The obvious solution is to separate content from presentation. Return your presentation structure and it includes a url where content can be fetched using an API that supports paging.